# specifying rake tasks to be run during gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

how do I specify that a rake task should be executed from within the gem installation process.

For example, if my Rakefile contains

```
spec = Gem::Specification.new do |s| 
  s.name = 'my_gem'

  # all the usual gem specification stuff

  s.files = FileList["{lib,images,test,test_data}/*"].to_a
  s.files << 'Rakefile'
end

Rake::GemPackageTask.new(spec){ |pkg| true}

desc 'My task'
task :my_task do 
  #some rake task
end
```

How do I instruct the gem installation process to run the rake task my_task as part of the gem installation procedure for my_gem; i.e. I wish to ensure that "gem install my_gem" calls "rake my_task" to complete the setup.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Would love to reopen this question, what is the best practice for this?

Comment: @hiattp - create a new question and point it at this one - explain how your situation is different. Alternatively, if your situation is the same, consider adding a bounty to this to get more attention.

Answer (score -1):

I'm kinda guessing - but I know that gems have an "install.rb" in them - perhaps it could be specified there?